# This should be a tough one

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, knowledge

> Oh my, oh my, my puzzling friends
>
> [My last riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69290/an-ode-to-puzzling?noredirect=1#comment207661_69290) is unsolved but for a
> few odds and ends.
>
> With no interaction, I've gotten quite bored.
>
> I wrote this riddle so I
> won't be ignored.
>
> I've got another word, four parts this time
>
> A prefix, a suffix, two infixes in this rhyme
>
> My prefix describes some folks you might know,
>
> who shun convention wherever they go.
>
> They're not rebellious, they don't break the rules,
>
> but you might find them ... strange in the things that they
> choose.
>
> If you know who they are, then know they aren't I
>
> For I am a different kind of guy
>
> For infix the first, I have a bad habit
>
> I am guilty myself, I have to admit.
>
> For this awkward thing manifests when I speak,
>
> And for many more too, especially the meek.
>
> Next infix is easy, you're doing it now,
>
> You don't think about it, but you do it, somehow.
>
> Take that and swap height with width, you are almost done,
>
> Infix 2 is now complete, and the suffix has begun.
>
> The puzzle's almost over, this is your destiny
>
> Just take the apple and throw it out, and closer you will be.
>
> Take what's left, chop it up, and give it to The Pope,
>
> If you have his help, there is still some hope.
>
> Good luck with this puzzle, give it your best try.
>
> If you figure out my name, then tell me. Who am I?

Hint #1

> I like the pope, don't get me wrong, but don't misconstrue.
>  I care not for religion, it matters not to you.
>  Because the pope is Latin, he matters to this rhyme.
>  With this added clue, you should solve the puzzle in time.

Comment: A rhyming riley riddle

Comment: I've written a few of those, you might have noticed

Comment: I'm rather fond of them. Maybe the great Riley him/herself can solve this

Comment: If my answer is right, @Cubemaster, then you're one crafty puzzle setter...

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie take a look at this! :D

Comment: This is my new favorite puzzle!

Comment: I would make one for  all the other regulars, but that would be too obvious now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Oh my goodness, did you create a meta puzzle?

> Are you QuantumTwinkie????

My prefix describes some folks you might know, 
who shun convention wherever they go. 
They're not rebellious, they don't break the rules, 
but you might find them ... strange in the things that they choose.

> These could be QUANTs (ie. quantitative analysts, ie. dataheads). These people tend to focus on the results and insights that the data tells them is true, rather than agreeing with "conventional wisdom".

For infix the first, I have a bad habit 
I am guilty myself, I have to admit. 
For this awkward thing manifests when I speak, 
And for many more too, especially the meek.

> When you stutter, you say the word UM.

Next infix is easy, you're doing it now, 
You don't think about it, but you do it, somehow. 
Take that and swap height with width, you are almost done, 
Infix 2 is now complete, and the suffix has begun.

> I definitely am THINKing right now, and I don't think about me thinking (FYI, that's metacognition, and we're not going there). When I swap Height with Width, then THINK becomes TWINK.

The puzzle's almost over, this is your destiny 
Just take the apple and throw it out, and closer you will be. 
Take what's left, chop it up, and give it to The Pope, 
If you have his help, there is still some hope.

> If you take the word DESTINY, and remove the Big Apple (New York, ie. NY), you get DESTI. This is a scrambled form of the words ID EST, a Latin phrase (remember the Pope?) that means "that is". The short form of ID EST is the suffix that we are looking for: IE. Thanks very much to @kayzeroshort for discovering the wordplay in this clue!!

Good luck with this puzzle, give it your best try. 
If you figure out my name, then tell me. Who am I?

> Putting it all together, you get QUANTUMTWINKIE, which would be a really amusing homage to your supposed "nemesis"!

Comment: the 'apple' part refers to [rot13](https://rot13.com)(gnxvat Arj Lbex, v.r. AL, bhg bs qrfgval, yrnivat n fpenzoyrq 'vq rfg', v.r. v.r.) :)

Comment: Thanks @kayzeroshort! I will update my answer and give you credit -- great find! :)

Comment: I can't tell you how happy I am that someone figured it out, and that person is not Mr. Twinkie himself

Answer (score 2):

I created an account just to post this guess, because I feel pretty good about it.

Are you

> Nocticula? Appears to be a God of Pathfinder.

My prefix describes some folks you might know,
who shun convention wherever they go.
They're not rebellious, they don't break the rules,
but you might find them ... strange in the things that they choose.
If you know who they are, then know they aren't I
For I am a different kind of guy

> Could definitely describe someone who is nocturnal.

For infix the first, I have a bad habit
I am guilty myself, I have to admit.
For this awkward thing manifests when I speak,
And for many more too, especially the meek.

> Some might develop a tick when under pressure, such as while speaking publicly.

Next infix is easy, you're doing it now,
You don't think about it, but you do it, somehow.
Take that and swap height with width, you are almost done,
Infix 2 is now complete, and the suffix has begun.

> I'm doing IT now. Not sure about the placement of this one, but it seems to make sense otherwise.

The puzzle's almost over, this is your destiny
Just take the apple and throw it out, and closer you will be.
Take what's left, chop it up, and give it to The Pope,
If you have his help, there is still some hope.

> I found a way to justify this one somehow but have forgotten it in the time I've taken to type the rest of this, which might be telling. BUT 'ula' is a Latin prefix. I might have just convinced myself this is wrong...

Comment: Ah. I see this was answered while I was writing my guess and the answer was well above my head. Disregard me.

Comment: I play a bit of pathfinder, I appreciate the reference

Answer (score 1):

2nd Attempt (somewhat comedic attempt):

My prefix describes some folks you might know,
who shun convention wherever they go.
They're not rebellious, they don't break the rules,
but you might find them ... strange in the things that they choose.
If you know who they are, then know they aren't I
For I am a different kind of guy

> This sounds like someone who is Queer (please don't stone me, I'm not trying to be offensive).

For infix the first, I have a bad habit
I am guilty myself, I have to admit.
For this awkward thing manifests when I speak,
And for many more too, especially the meek.

> This sounds like someone who mumbles. queer-mumble?

Next infix is easy, you're doing it now,
You don't think about it, but you do it, somehow.
Take that and swap height with width, you are almost done,
Infix 2 is now complete, and the suffix has begun.

> I'm pretty sure this is referring to seeing something, or C. When you swap the width for the height, you are left with the letter U. so queer-mumble-u.

The puzzle's almost over, this is your destiny
Just take the apple and throw it out, and closer you will be.
Take what's left, chop it up, and give it to The Pope,
If you have his help, there is still some hope.

> Maybe I was taking this the wrong way last time. When you throw out Apple computers, you are left with windows! So let's chop it up, give it to the pope, who provides for the meek and weary, and we are left with widow. So Queer-mumble-u-widow.

The answer is of course,

> quemumbleuwidow, which we all know means to be left baffled by a made-up word.

---

I believe the answer is

> Emotionalism, though I can't figure out what the second infix and suffix have to do with this.

My prefix describes some folks you might know,
who shun convention wherever they go.
They're not rebellious, they don't break the rules,
but you might find them ... strange in the things that they choose.
If you know who they are, then know they aren't I
For I am a different kind of guy

> This sounds like someone who is emo.

For infix the first, I have a bad habit
I am guilty myself, I have to admit.
For this awkward thing manifests when I speak,
And for many more too, especially the meek.

> This sounds like pacing. So we have emo-motion. emotion?

Next infix is easy, you're doing it now,
You don't think about it, but you do it, somehow.
Take that and swap height with width, you are almost done,
Infix 2 is now complete, and the suffix has begun.

> I'm pretty sure this is referring to breathing, so maybe breath? emotion-breath.

The puzzle's almost over, this is your destiny
Just take the apple and throw it out, and closer you will be.
Take what's left, chop it up, and give it to The Pope,
If you have his help, there is still some hope.

> If you throw out the apple, you'd be left with the seeds? Pope and seeds, poppyseed? So we have emotion-breath-poppyseed. That can't be right. How about emotionalism?

I believe the answer is

> Emotionalism, though I can't figure out what the second infix and suffix have to do with this.

Comment: This might just be the farthest from the correct answer you have ever been.

Comment: Well, I gave it a shot. I really thought I got the first two right.

Comment: In my experience, emo people are pretty rebellious. That said, good effort!

Comment: To be fair, I think this might be my sneakiest one yet

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:

Prefix:

> Hipster

Infix1:

> Stuttering or mumbling

Infix2:

> Breadth ( as in width)

Suffix:

> Blessed Core