# Riddles to Be, I Challenge The!

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

So I'm a fan of the work from several users here on Puzzling; but there is one in particular that I would love to see a riddle from! Can you guess who it is?

> Entrancing with answers, for our patrons in-depth;
>
> Leading with research, a client unlike the rest.

**Note**: I'm looking for a user-name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it

> [El-Guest](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/50778/el-guest)

Entrancing with answers,

> He is very good at solving a multitude of questions.

for our patrons in-depth;

> He gets the clues without OP comments usually.

Leading with research,

> He does [research](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70853/who-is-petes-favourite-composer/70858#comment212005_70858).

a client unlike the rest.

> Maybe because his name contains "guest".

Hidden hint

> The first letter of each line spells "EL"

Comment: This is pretty funny! You got me back!

Comment: Lol, that is pretty funny :)

Comment: So you managed to answer this so fast that I can't even accept it yet! I knew it was too easy. He's pretty well known on the site here! How about it @El-Guest? Someday perhaps?

Comment: For those not aware, I answered a [similar puzzle a few weeks ago](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69318/this-should-be-a-tough-one) and now the favour has been returned!

Comment: Haha, that's great! I didn't see that one.

Comment: @PerpetualJ Your Lines were a giveaway. I saw the hidden hint immediately.

Comment: What's funny is the words *patrons* and *client* were actually the hints. I really need to get away from acrostics for a while. :D