# The most dangerous game

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge

> Hello again, remember me?
>
> It's been a while, certainly
>
> I've not been round for quite some time,
>
> But now I have another rhyme
>
> In my normal style, I have a word
>
> It's in 3 parts, but rest assured.
>
> It should be easier than [my last](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69290/an-ode-to-puzzling?noredirect=1&lq=1)
>
> So do your best to solve it fast
>
> When last we met, you went on a quest, just after breakfasttime.
>
> A suffix you were seeking, but it is not mine.
>
> You did not find your
> treasure, but there is time enough.
>
> Sit down, take a rest, this one won't be as tough.
>
> ---
>
> My prefix you use nearly every day,
>
> But if you are from England, you say it in this way.
>
> Just take care to do it privately,
>
> That's not something we all want to see.
>
> If you feel like resting, we have some games to play.
>
> Oh, maybe not that one, It might just ruin your day.
>
> Not that you'd be bad, it's just rather hard
>
> You'll probably die so much, you'll forever be scarred
>
> If you kill some stuff and ring some bells, you will get to see..
>
> The fortress of my infix, full of treachery.
>
> If that game's too tough, then that's okay, you won't be far behind.
>
> My infix doesn't matter much, it's just a lucky find
>
> I should note, the best part of that game is the jolly cooperation,
>
> But you won't get much of that without my suffix in your station.
>
> With all that gaming, you must be hungry. You should make some dinner
>
> Just don't try to eat me, or you won't be a winner.
>
> You have a lot to think about, and two puzzles to try.
>
> If you find this one out, then tell me. What am I?

Comment: Wow! I had no clue riley riddles could be this long

Comment: At some point this year, Imma make a long long long Riley Riddle. So long, it will be longer than the OP's... and we will see who can write the longest... mwahahahaha

Comment: Sometimes a riddle of this length can be a curse too, because it makes it harder to solve. Still, I enjoy writing them.

Comment: By the way, just to clear the air before answers start rolling in, the actual meat of the riddle is below the dividing line. Everything above is just flavor.

Comment: In my answer, I skipped the part of the riddle above the line after reading your comment :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's see if I can make some progress here...are you

> ARSENIC?

My prefix you use nearly every day, 
But if you are from England, you say it in this way. 
Just take care to do it privately, 
That's not something we all want to see.

> This is your rear end, or in England, your ARSE

If you feel like resting, we have some games to play. 
Oh, maybe not that one, It might just ruin your day. 
Not that you'd be bad, it's just rather hard 
You'll probably die so much, you'll forever be scarred

> This sounds like  <strike>Dank</strike>  Dark Souls, full credit to @Elpharya for recognizing this reference. Thanks, from one El to another!

If you kill some stuff and ring some bells, you will get to see.. 
The fortress of my infix, full of treachery. 
If that game's too tough, then that's okay, you won't be far behind. 
My infix doesn't matter much, it's just a lucky find

> This refers to the fortress of SEN, according to @Elpharya.

I should note, the best part of that game is the jolly cooperation, 
But you won't get much of that without my suffix in your station.

> You need some integrated circuits, or ICs, in your station. From @Cubemaster, you also need a Network Interface Card, or NIC. Thanks!!

With all that gaming, you must be hungry. You should make some dinner 
Just don't try to eat me, or you won't be a winner.

> Unlike LOOSENERs, ARSENIC is actually truly bad for you.

You have a lot to think about, and two puzzles to try. 
If you find this one out, then tell me. What am I?

> Hopefully ARSENIC!

Comment: Very close. You got the infix, and you are on the right track with the prefix

Comment: Also, Is there a concrete thing called a "loosener"? if so I have never seen one

Comment: For looseners, there's [this](https://www.brodi.com/turn-heavy-duty-nut-amp-bolt-loosener), and more famously [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=viejY6UZ5Bk).

Comment: Ohhhhhh I think I got it now @Cubemaster

Comment: Well done! The suffix was supposed to be NIC as in Network Interface Card, but you got it nonetheless!

Comment: Thanks! I've made the suggested edit as well! Now on to your hardest one... ;)

Comment: Good luck, it is a doozy

Answer (score 3):

I have a fun feeling this has something to do with...

> Dark Souls!

My prefix you use nearly every day,

But if you are from England, you say it in this way.

Just take care to do it privately,

That's not something we all want to see.

> This one I'm still figuring out

If you feel like resting, we have some games to play.

Oh, maybe not that one, It might just ruin your day.

Not that you'd be bad, it's just rather hard

You'll probably die so much, you'll forever be scarred

> Dark Souls is known for being a tough game, where it's quite common for players to die frequently. Also, once you die in Dark Souls, you return as a "hollow", who appears scarred.

If you kill some stuff and ring some bells, you will get to see..

The fortress of my infix, full of treachery.

If that game's too tough, then that's okay, you won't be far behind.

My infix doesn't matter much, it's just a lucky find

> By ringing the "Bells of Awakening", you gain entrance into "Sen's Fortress", leading me to conclude the infix = SEN

I should note, the best part of that game is the jolly cooperation,

But you won't get much of that without my suffix in your station.

With all that gaming, you must be hungry. You should make some dinner

Just don't try to eat me, or you won't be a winner.

> "Jolly Cooperation" is an iconic phrase by Solaire of Astora in Dark Souls. Cooperative games need something in your (play)station, so the suffix could be play, wifi, disc, or maybe something along those lines?

You have a lot to think about, and two puzzles to try.
If you find this one out, then tell me. What am I?

> Not too sure quite yet

Comment: Firstly, welcome to the puzzling stack exchange! Secondly, nice work on solving that infix, and you are very close to the suffix

Comment: Thanks! I'm having a blast so far. I'll keep working at it!

Answer (score 0):

`My prefix you use nearly every day,` 
`But if you are from England, you say it in this way.` 
 
`Just take care to do it privately,` 
 `That's not something we all want to see.`

> Could the prefix be **EYE**? 
>  You use it nearly everyday (because around the last couple hours of the day, you are sleeping). The England part refers to the English idiom, *you can* ***say*** *that again*, which indicates the prefix reference might be true. Or it could refer to the idiom, to *have eyes at the back of your head*. 
>  
>  "Take care of your eyes **pri**vately" (a ship between the sounds of **prefix** and **eye**, namely, **pri**). Also, things that are private aren't supposed to be seen (otherwise they are not private), and you use your **eyes** to see.

`If you feel like resting, we have some games to play.` 
`Oh, maybe not that one, It might just ruin your day.` 
`Not that you'd be bad, it's just rather hard.` 
`You'll probably die so much, you'll forever be scarred.` 
`If you kill some stuff and ring some bells, you will get to see..`

> *We* might refer to the *pair* of **eyes**, which could be what the first paragraph referred to. Eyes that play tricks on you (a.k.a **hallucinations**) can, most likely, ruin your day. This in particular might refer to hallucinations because the word has the same prefix as *hard* (**ha**llucination, **ha**rd), and we were just talking about prefixes. When you die, you can't see anything; and since you can't come back from the dead (according to science, not belief) then the scar really is forever. 
>  
>  I am not too sure about the killing of stuff and ringing bells, but the consequence is **sight**. And, resting could refer to death, although rest is not forever (unless it is a coma, but that is beyond topic). So my take on "resting" is that it refers to sleeping. In your sleep, you can dream and see things, but you are not using your eyes.

`The fortress of my infix, full of treachery.` 
`If that game's too tough, then that's okay, you won't be far behind.` 
`My infix doesn't matter much, it's just a lucky find` 
`I should note, the best part of that game is the jolly cooperation,` 
`But you won't get much of that without my suffix in your station.`

> Could the infix be **GLASS**? 
>  A fortress of glass could be a window or mirror. When cold, windows can get foggy, making it difficult to see through them; when steam rises from a shower, mirrors can also get foggy. That might explain the treachery part, and that game might be too tough because you won't be able to **see** (through the window, or yourself on the mirror). 
>  
>  Also, you won't be far behind because you might be wearing **glasses** (to see if you have trouble seeing), and your **eyes** are not too **far behind** them. It is a lucky **find** since glass is **transparent**, and you can use its potential fortresses mentioned before to **see** (and the word **find** rhymes with **blind**, for which if you are just that, you cannot see). It refers to *you* and not *eyes* because we use our eyes to learn of **location**. The jolly cooperation could refer to **GLASSES**, and you won't get that without the suffix, **ES**.

Therefore, could the word be

> **EYEGLASSES**?

`With all that gaming, you must be hungry. You should make some dinner` 
`Just don't try to eat me, or you won't be a winner.` 
`You have a lot to think about, and two puzzles to try.`

> To not be able to see, it could be stressful, and it is common for people to **eat** when they are stressed. Also, if you eat **glass**... yeah, don't eat glass. The two puzzles might refer to the two **words** in the overall word (**EYE**, **GLASSES**).

`If you find this one out, then tell me. What am I?`

> If you **find** this **one** out, then tell me (where the word "one" refers to how an **EYEGLASS** is used for **one** eye, as opposed to just **glasses**). What am **I** (**eye**)? 
>  Could you be **EYEGLASSES**?

---

**Title:**

`The most dangerous game`

> It is dangerous to not see, and also, performing operations on the eye can be dangerous. How is the latter related? Well, an anagram of **DANGEROUS GAME** is **SURGEON DAMAGE**.

Comment: Well, you are a bit late to the party, but I like the attempt. Bit of a stretch though

Comment: @Cubemaster I don't play video games... I used to play Rot13(Qnex Fbhyf) but not anymore, and this riddle made me think of that game, but I looked at one of the other answers and wanted to try a different approach :)

Comment: Yeah, the reference to that game was pretty obvious, but I like your approach!

Comment: @Cubemaster I am trying to look for an answer of mine. I swear I have referenced the game in that answer :P