# The "Three Diamond" Distilling Company

Tags: lateral-thinking, knowledge, story

Now, I grew up in South Carolina. Most people don't associate my home state with bootleggin', but, back in the day, this is where it all began. Ya see, the fastest cars could outrun those cop cars. So if you had the fastest hot rod out there, you could move 'liquid gold' and the feds [couldn't do nothing](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70658/double-negatives-rule) about it. That's how [NASCAR](https://auto.howstuffworks.com/auto-racing/nascar/history/nascar-bootleggers.htm) began! My grandpappy bootlegged in a Mitsubishi, hence [the title of this post](https://www.betweentheaxles.net/mitsubishi-etymology-what-does-its-name-mean-8506).

So one day, not too long ago, I put a full bottle of my finest, oldest hootch in the freezer. I'd been saving it for a long time, and a special occasion was coming up. Much to my surprise, a few days later I noticed that it had done been accosted! Little while later, I looked again, and now, it was half-gone! It seemed like someone or somethin' was a-swallerin' it up, day by day, little by little. Try as I might, I couldn't catch the thief. Then on that one day, the one I had been waitin' for, it was totally gone.

This time, though, I caught the sonofabitch.

> Who was the culprit, and on what ***exact*** day did I figure out what had happened?

Comment: Are rude words actually allowed (just asking) :)

Comment: @KevinL What rude words are you talking about?

Comment: The "sonofabitch" or does that not count :)

Comment: More of one word

Comment: Feb 21 because that's the day nascar started and the same day that you saw it was happening

Comment: @Duck It's generally frowned upon to give answers (or even partial guesses) in comments.

Comment: $(+1)$ for the guts to say sonofabitch on a public site :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the date may have been

> July 27th, 2018

and the culprit was the riddle author taking things too literally:

> The special occasion was the much anticipated [lunar eclipse](http://earthsky.org/tonight/centurys-longest-lunar-eclipse-july-27): as it progressed toward totality, the *moonshine* gradually disappeared from the bottle too.

Here are a couple of the relevant clues, I may very well have missed some:

> The [flag of South Carolina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_South_Carolina) has a really weird looking moon on it; clearly it [cannot be a crescent moon](https://xkcd.com/1738/), so it has to be an eclipse.
>
>  Mitsubishi makes a car called [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitsubishi_Eclipse).

And of course, the whole story is about making and selling self-distilled liquor, for which the riddle uses a couple of other nicknames, but cleverly avoids ever mentioning

> "moonshiners" and "moonshine".

Comment: To be honest, I'm considering accepting this answer (it's very good and very close to what I was thinking.) That said, my intended culprit was *not* the speaker, the date was longer ago than this, and the days that passed were actually days, not minutes).