# I exist in the middle of the seven

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I am a haven for those with thick walls

I challenge convention with my transparent skin

My effect is quite big, though I can be small

I keep the bad stuff out, and the good stuff in.

---

What am I?

Comment: If you're European, a cross. Your Zs too.

Comment: Maybe a Jellyfish?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

How about a

> greenhouse

I am a haven for those with thick walls

> like plants, whose thick walls refer to their stems
>  Also, like BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft suggested, plant cells normally have thick cell walls

I challenge convention with my transparent skin

> greenhouses use transparent material (while plants are normally planted outside in the garden or in a house

My effect is quite big, though I can be small

> greenhouses, even if they're small, can be effective at retaining heat

I keep the bad stuff out, and the good stuff in.

> they can keep the bad stuff (chills, winds, bugs, etc) out, and the good stuff, like heat, in

EDIT: In regards to the title, with credit to user BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft

> the seven refers to the seven colours of the rainbow: ROYGBIV, where the middle is G -> green

Comment: Tell me, how does this fit the title?

Comment: Dang, you beat me. It fits the title because of rot13(ebltovi, t = terra). Also, I thought "thick walls" referred to rot13(pryy jnyyf, juvpu ner [hahfhnyyl guvpx va cynagf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_wall#Plant_cell_walls))

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft ooh smart I didnt think of that. I'll update my answer (crediting you of course) after class :)

Comment: Pretty sure "Big effect" refers to the rot13(terraubhfr rssrpg va gur ngzbfcurer)

Comment: I like what rot13 does with "terra"

Answer (score 15):

I doubt this is your intended answer, but it amuses me, so here we go:

> Stack Exchange

How in the world do I come to that?

> The title is "I exist in the middle of the seven", If I take that literally, "se" are the center two characters of t-h-e-s-e-v-e-n.  And, as everyone around here knows, "SE" means Stack Exchange.

So, how does this fit with the rest of your riddle?

I am a haven for those with thick walls

> SE is *the* place to go to get answers when you are stuck.  I've often described being stuck as "pounding my head against a wall", so, when I am really stuck, it has to be a thick wall, and SE is my haven.

I challenge convention with my transparent skin

> The model of self-governance on the web is both transparent, and runs counter to the convention that there needs to be some sort of elected / owning entity that moderates the place.

My effect is quite big, though I can be small

> Stack Exchange is where I usually wind up after Googling one of my programming questions.  SE is nowhere near the size of Google, but its effects have been massive for me!

I keep the bad stuff out, and the good stuff in.

> With the voting and reputation system, good answers get more prominence on a page, bad ones drop off, if they get enough down votes.

OK, so I may be being a little tongue-in-cheek with my answer (I'd be surprised if it was Cubemaster's intended answer), but it certainly fits the bill!

Comment: Lol not quite, but the funny thing is that I do have a riddle with that exact answer. Check [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69290/an-ode-to-puzzling) out

Comment: @Cubemaster good to know that at least you *might* have thought along these lines!

Answer (score 12):

Are you:

> A window?

I am a haven for those with thick walls

> Windows let light enter the house, especially useful when your walls are thick.

I challenge convention with my transparent skin

> Transparent skin probably refers to the fact that the window is transparent I.e. made of glass.

My effect is quite big, though I can be small

> Windows let light in, which is a huge effect, but they are small.

I keep the bad stuff out, and the good stuff in.

> Self-explanatory: windows keep dirt out but let light in.

Comment: Very close, but not quite! How does a window being transparent challenge convention though? In my memory, windows have always been transparent.

Comment: @Cubemaster you are right, that’s why I’m not sure about my answer.

Comment: You are certainly on the right track. Keep up the effort!

Answer (score 10):

Same answer as @Elpharya, with different reasoning:

You are a:

> Greenhouse

I am a haven for those with thick walls

> You contain plants which have cell rigid walls. (As opposed to animal cells which do not have cell walls.)

I challenge convention with my transparent skin

> Unlike a conventional house, which is opaque.

My effect is quite big, though I can be small

> The greenhouse effect is a global issue. Whereas a greenhouse is a small structure.

I keep the bad stuff out, and the good stuff in.

> Cold stays out, heat comes in.

As for the title:

> EDIT: Lifted from @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft's comment on @Elpharya's answer: The seven refers to the seven colours of the rainbow red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo, violet. With green being the middle one.

Comment: Exactly right, and right reasoning to boot. I'm conflicted whether to accept Elpharya's or yours. He got it first, but you got the perfect reasoning...

Comment: This is a fantastic answer!

Answer (score 7):

Are you

> Eyes (or the transparent bit at the front thereof)?

I am a haven for those with thick walls

> Animals have relatively thick skin (compared with yours).

I challenge convention with my transparent skin

> Skin is not usually transparent, but yours is.

My effect is quite big, though I can be small

> You enable sight, a big advantage though you are relatively small.

I keep the bad stuff out, and the good stuff in.

> You allow light into the retina while keeping dust and stuff out.

You exist in the middle of seven.

> Famously, we have 7 holes in our heads and you exist in the middle of two of them.

Comment: Not quite. I would agree that eyes are quite a useful thing for us to have, but I don't quite know if they qualify as a "haven" in the right sense. I'm glad you tried to fit the title into it though, that does play a part in the solution. Keep up the effort!

Answer (score 5):

Throwing this guess out there, are you:

> The US justice system, maybe the Supreme Court specifically? (not trying to take a political stand one way or another)

I am a haven for those with thick walls

> (Big stretch) The US Constitution is supposed to treat everyone fairly, so it should be a safe haven for those oppressed (maybe referring to a literal or figurative jail)?

I challenge convention with my transparent skin

> The SC has been involved with [huge decisions](https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/politics/2015/06/26/supreme-court-cases-history/29185891/) that challenged the norm.  Rulings are public.

My effect is quite big, though I can be small

> What the SC decides has a sweeping effect over the entire US, despite being only 9 members (and only a 5 votes are needed).

I keep the bad stuff out, and the good stuff in.

> Bad laws are overturned/rules unconstitutional, good ones are kept.

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for, but I like it! It actually fits pretty well here. Nice!

Answer (score 5):

How about a

> lightbulb

I am a haven for those with thick walls

> no light gets in to places with thick walls (or a cave!)

I challenge convention with my transparent skin

> skin is made of glass

My effect is quite big, though I can be small

> Can be very small and light a whole room

I keep the bad stuff out, and the good stuff in.

> Lightbulbs need a low pressure inhert gas in order to light up. Too much pressure or oxygen and they burn up!

I exist in the middle of the seven

> possibly a lighthouse, on the 7 seas?

Answer (score 4):

Are you a

> cell membrane?

I am a haven for those with thick walls

> Thick cell walls(eg. plant cells), membrane acts to control contents of a cell

I challenge convention with my transparent skin

My effect is quite big, though I can be small

I keep the bad stuff out, and the good stuff in.

> cell membranes are extremely thin and transparant but act as a potent barrier from the outside. They can control what enters and leaves the cell

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange! You are certainly on the right track, but not quite there. See if you can use what you have to find something that fits all of the clues!

Answer (score 3):

I am a haven for those with thick walls

> Water, in case of a siege.

I challenge convention with my transparent skin

> Surface tension skin

My effect is quite big, though I can be small

> Giving life vs being a droplet

I keep the bad stuff out, and the good stuff in.

> Drinking 8 cups of water, lots of water and rest, etc

I exist in the middle of the seven

> 7 continents

How come no one takes the title as one of the clues? Am I wrong to do so? Anyway, my answer is

> Water

Comment: "7 continents" could also refer to [the seven seas](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Seas)

Answer (score 2):

Along the line of Krad Cigol's answer which was 'on the right track'.

Are you a

> Skylight

I am a haven for those with thick walls

> Thick walls mean that windows less effective... outside light has to come from a skylight.

I challenge convention with my transparent skin

> Ceilings/roofs are typically opaque

My effect is quite big, though I can be small

> even a small skylight can light an entire room

I keep the bad stuff out, and the good stuff in.

> Skylight keeps out the weather and the warm in...

Comment: Close, but no cigar.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have it! (Great puzzle, by the way, even if I'm not right)

I think that the answer is

> [**Translucent concrete**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translucent_concrete)

I am a haven for those with thick walls

> Concrete provides thick, strong walls

I challenge convention with my transparent skin

> We always think of concrete as opaque, but these technological developments allow light to pass through the concrete.

My effect is quite big, though I can be small

> A little light goes a long way; also, the fibers that bring in the light can be quite small.

I keep the bad stuff out, and the good stuff in.

> In a building that uses translucent concrete, dust and dirt stays out, robbers stay out, pests stay out, but light comes in through the concrete, and the people that are supposed to come in can use the door.

Comment: @Cubemaster how close am I?

Answer (score 1):

I know you have given an answer but I have an even better solution :P

> Pride, one of the 7 deadly sins!

I am a haven for those with thick walls

> Thick walls could mean that a person does not like to show weakness or emotion. pride can facilitate this

I challenge convention with my transparent skin

> Pride is an idea rather than a solid. Transparent skin could be a metaphor

My effect is quite big, though I can be small

> Again, pride can have a massive effect from a tiny idea, misconception etc.

I keep the bad stuff out, and the good stuff in.

> bad and good can be subjective. Too much pride means that you would not want to hear different 'bad' opinions. You can convince yourself that your own 'wrong' opinions are good with too much of it

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> A one-way mirror?

I am a haven for those with thick walls

> A one-way mirror is used in criminal identification investigations.

I challenge convention with my transparent skin

> Even though it is transparent, one cannot see through it when on the correct side.

My effect is quite big, though I can be small

> One may look through a rather small one-way mirror to investigate quite a bit.

I keep the bad stuff out, and the good stuff in.

> Keep the suspected criminals away from the witness?

As for the title,

> Perhaps you are referring to the 7 deadly sins, in which case **envy** would be in the middle, and a mirror can most certainly allow one to envy him or herself.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that might fit

> [Lichen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lichen) is a type of fungus that has cyanobacteria or algae living inside them.

I will readily admit that some clues may be a bit far fetched but it was fun to read up on this on Wikipedia.

---

I am a haven for those with thick walls

> Cyanobacteria that live inside the fungus have cell walls

I challenge convention with my transparent skin

> The fungus relies of photosynthesis of a different organism *inside* its translucent filaments. It's like a small greenhouse!

My effect is quite big, though I can be small

> Lichens are small organisms, however, according to Wikipedia: *indeed, in some desert ecosystems, vascular (higher) plant seeds cannot become established except in places where lichen crusts stabilize the sand and help retain water.*

I keep the bad stuff out, and the good stuff in.

> The symbiotic relationship is based on the fact that the fungus is able to retain water and gather nutrients from the air, and providing an anchor to the crucial photosynthesis-capable organisms inside it.

As for the title,

> This answer was in fact inspired by the title. I figured that maybe it had something to do with organisms, and according to some scientists, there are [seven kingdoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_(biology)#Seven_kingdoms) of organisms. Here, 'in the middle' is taken as 'amidst' rather than 'centered'. A lichen is amidst all the kingdoms, being a composite organism of fungi, bacteria and/or algae.

Answer (score 0):

Could totally be a

> One way mirror

I am a haven for those with thick walls

> A one way mirror, makes the criminal feel like he is not seen, and suspected, hereby letting his "walls" down.

I challenge convention with my transparent skin

> I mean... mirrors aren't usually transparent, but this one is.

My effect is quite big, though I can be small

> The effect of one way mirrors in an interrogation room, has been proven to be quite big.

I keep the bad stuff out, and the good stuff in.

> keeps the criminal out of the officers room, and keeps them safe and unspotted inside.

I exist in the middle of the seven

> In the middle of the word "Seven" is a V, which in itself is a mirrored "\" - furthermore, in Lithuanian, the word for mirror is "veidrodis" - beginning with a V

Answer (score -1):

I think the answer is

> A clear glass bottle of alcohol

I am a haven for those with thick walls

> People that do not want to talk about problems are often said to be putting up walls. People often consume alcohol to relieve the stress.

I challenge convention with my transparent skin

> Glass bottles were [first created around 100 BC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glass_bottle). Modern day, all bottles are not made from transparent glass (think plastic bottles and dark colored beer glass bottles). I would guess that there are more bottles made from plastic (like water/pop bottles) than glass.

My effect is quite big, though I can be small

> Even a small amount of alcohol can get a person drunk.

I keep the bad stuff out, and the good stuff in.

> Alcohol is often referred to as ["the good stuff"](https://luxury.rehabs.com/blog/alcohol-the-good-stuff-and-the-not-so-good-stuff/). The bottle keeps the alcohol from getting contaminated.

I exist in the middle of the seven

> This is a little big of a stretch, but I think this is a reference to the seven deadly sins. Gluttony (drunkenness) was in the middle of a few of the lists that I Googled.